# Vue js "this" is overridden with image.onload "this"

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue app. I use `this.data` to access it's data variables and methods.

In a certain method I have to use img.onload to get the width of an image. But there are 2 "**this**" now and vue js methods and variables are not working now. I need an alternative solution so both will work.

```
vueMethod(url) {
 var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function() {
  this.size = {this.width,this.height}  //size is a vue variable
 }
 img.src = url;
}
```

Comment: so using a function creates a new scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign `this` to a variable called `vm` before calling  `img.onload` function as follows

```
vueMethod(url) {
  var img = new Image();
  let vm = this;
  img.onload = function() {
    vm.size = { this.width, this.height }  //size is a vue variable
  }
  img.src = url;
}
```

Comment: using an arrow function would make more sense

Comment: this.size wouldnt work? as this refers to the image also

Comment: think you've got it mixed up should be, ` vm.size = {width: this.width, height: this.height}`

Comment: Thank you! You saved a lot of my time

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `arrow function` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) to keep the englobing scope:

```
vueMethod(url) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    this.size = {img.width, img.height}
  }
  img.src = url;
}
```

In this example, `this` will have the same reference as if you used it next to `var img`

Comment: While technically correct, this won't work, because he needs both scopes...

Comment: I believe it's not a good practice to use arrow function when the scope already has a `this` context

Answer (score 1):

You should save Vue instance into a variable outside the `img.onload` scope
try with:

```
vueMethod(url) {
  var img = new Image();
  var vm = this;
  img.onload = function() {
      vm.size = {this.width,this.height}  //size is a vue variable
  }
  img.src = url;
}
```

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for the upcoming vote back, good coding!

Answer (score 0):

Put `var that = this;` inside your img funciton.

That will give you scope in your function, or bind your function when you call it e.g

```
vueMethod("url").bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you use a function with the keyword `function` it creates a new scope for this to refer to consider the below example

```
const obj = {
  size: 10,
  testFunc() {
   console.log(this, 'now obj')

   const func = function () {
     // this now refers to function its currently in
   }
   const otherFunc = () => console.log(this, 'refers to obj still')
  },
  testFunc2: () => {
    console.log(this, 'now window')
  }
}
```

any questions let me know and i'll be happy to help

```js
const obj = {
  size: 10,

  vueMethod(url) {
    console.log(this.size, 'this now refers to obj')
    const img = new Image();
    const self = this;

    img.onload = function() {
      console.log(this, 'this now refers to img')
      console.log(self.size, 'but you can reassign this to a var outside the scope');

      self.size = {
        width: this.width,
        height: this.height
      }
    };
    // mocking the onload dont include this
    img.onload();
    img.src = url;
  }
}

obj.vueMethod()
```